# What should be an approach for loading data using joins from rdbms database to spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdbms

I am new to Spark 2.4 and trying to figure out the best approach for bringing data from GreenPlum/PostgreSQL to Spark.

Is it better to load data from RDBMS using a join query or individually load tables using partition by DB column and then have spark joins?

A native query with joins across multiple huge tables works with the below code but not sure whether it is a correct approach or not also not sure how we can give a partition.

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
    .option("user", "user1")
    .option("password", "password1")
    .option("query", "select a.*, b.* from a join on b a.user_id = b.user_id)
    //not sure what should go here for query with multiple joins.
    //.option("partitionColumn", "*")
```

Comment: I would think offloading the operation to the database rather than Spark would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the fastest option is to first load the data in parallel from RDBMS to the cluster storage: HDFS or S3 for example. You will do it similarly to your current load statement, but you will define partitions for the table first using the properties `partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound` (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html). This is very fast in general. The only drawback is that you need a numeric column which has equally distributed values in the best case: auto incrementing ids or timestamps are generally quite good.

Computationally heavy operations on really huge tables are often way faster if performed using scalable engines like spark.

Comment: Getting to HDFS or S3 is not possible in my case. partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound I know how they work on a single table but not sure what would be the values for a join query. The tables have a primary key which is of type Long and is incremental. @Elmar Macek

Comment: You can of course also store it in the local normal filestorage of your spark nodes. The partitioning will not work properly when used on a table that you define by a query like that of a join: the whole result has to be created in the database before any results are streamed to the cluster afaik. So my recommendation would still be: first get the data from the db and persist it as ORC or PARQUET. Then do the join using spark.